# js: true flag causes rspec tests to fail on Capybara-WebKit

Tags: javascript, rspec-rails, capybara-webkit

I have had this issue for over a week now. I am working on a multi-tenancy project using Apartment gem. I wanted to test JavaScript features with all database configs setup as recommended everywhere using Capybara-WebKit driver. However, I couldn't get it work, cos my FacotryGirl instance are not saved. Could anyone see part of these codes and give some suggestion?

rails_helper.rb:

```
    RSpec.configure do |config|
               .
               .
      config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
      config.add_setting(:seed_tables)

      config.before(:suite) do
        #DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
        DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, {except: config.seed_tables})
      end

      # Before each spec run, just to insure consistency between specs
      config.before(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
      end

      config.before(:each, :js => true) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {except: config.seed_tables}
      end

      config.before(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.start
      end

      # After each spec run, just to insure consistency between specs
      config.after(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
        Apartment::Tenant.reset
        drop_schemas
        Capybara.app_host = 'http://example.com'
        reset_mailer
      end
    end

    Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
      config.integrate do |with|
        with.test_framework :rspec
        with.library :rails
      end
    end

    Capybara.configure do |config|
      config.app_host = 'http://example.com'
      config.javascript_driver = :webkit
      config.always_include_port = true
    end

    Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
      # Allow a specific domain without issuing a warning.
      config.allow_url("lvh.me")

      # Wildcards are allowed in URL expressions.
      config.allow_url("*.lvh.me")
    end
```

RSpec:

```
   

    describe 'invoices' do
      let!(:account) { create(:account_with_schema) }
      let(:user) { account.owner }

      before do  
        set_subdomain(account.subdomain)
        sign_user_in(user)
        @customer = create(:customer)
      end

      describe 'when invoice exists' do
        before(:each) do
          @invoice = create(:invoice, user: user, customer: @customer,        
                     deadline: Date.tomorrow, payment_term: '')
          visit invoices_path

          click_link I18n.t('button.show')
          expect(page).to have_text @invoice.date_of_an_invoice
          expect(page).to have_text @invoice.customer.name
          expect(page).to have_text @invoice.reference_number

          expect(page).to have_link I18n.t('button.delete')
          expect(page).to have_link I18n.t('button.edit')
        end

        it 'allows invoice to be deleted', js: true do
          click_link I18n.t('button.delete')

          wait_for_ajax

          expect(page).to have_text    
              I18n.t('invoices.destroy.confirmation_msg')

          within('.modal-footer') do
            click_link I18n.t('button.delete')
          end

          expect(page).to have_text I18n.t('invoices.destroy.success_delete')
          expect(page).to_not have_text @invoice.date_of_an_invoice
          expect(page).to_not have_text @invoice.customer
        end
      end

    end
```

So, test fails on the click_link I18n.t('button.show') line in the `before` block of the 'when invoices exists' description. The 'Show' button is found on the @invoice instance basically, I did the save_and_open_page to investigate the issue and the @invoice instance is not there.

Error:

```
Failures:

  1) invoices when invoice exists allows invoice to be deleted
     Failure/Error: click_link I18n.t('button.show')

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link "Show"
     # /home/birhanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:44:in `block in find'
     # /home/birhanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
     # /home/birhanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:33:in `find'
     # /home/birhanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:27:in `click_link'
     # /home/birhanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:699:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # /home/birhanu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/invoices_feature_spec.rb:77:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 18.5 seconds (files took 6.39 seconds to load)
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/invoices_feature_spec.rb:110 # invoices when invoice exists allows invoice to be deleted
```

**NB** All tests are passed as expected when not using the js: true flag

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @TomWalpole I have updated the question with error logs pasted ^

Comment: After -  `visit invoices_path` do  `sleep 3;  page.save_screenshot`  and look at the saved image to see if the page is as you expect it -  If it's not what you expect because the user isn't logged in then check your `sign_user_in` method and make sure it's waiting at the end for the login to succeed, if it's not it's possible for the visit to occur before the response from logging in has set the session cookies

Comment: I have tried that eariler as well. I can see I am on the invoice page which is an authorized page so, the sign_use_in function let the user logged in. I have resolved all DNS related issue so, paths and sessions works fine as expected on webkit driver as well. What I don't see the new invoice instances which supposed to be created by this line `@invoice = create(:invoice, user: user, customer: @customer, deadline: Date.tomorrow, payment_term: '')`. Notice, all of these stuff work on rack_test driver.

Comment: Yes, I realize it works with the rack_test driver, and your database mode configuration looks correct -which is why I was having you check asynchronous issues that can occur with JS drivers.  The last thing to check would be your test log for the SQL queries that are actually occurring.  Additionally, wait_for_ajax shouldn't be required where you have it since `have_text` will wait automatically

Comment: Also your  database cleaner `after` block should be an `append_after` to prevent issues down the road - see https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example

Comment: Tried changing the `after` with `append_after`, didn't solve the issue. Thank you for your consistent effort, though!

Comment: I didn't think the `append_after` would solve this issue, but it should be that to prevent out of order database clearing issues in the future - can you post the output of doing  `sleep 5; puts page.html` before the click_link and the test.log output for this test.